# Can I replace percentages in legend with another value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I would like to change the default percentages shown in a Google Sheets Pie Chart with the actual dollar values. Is that possible? I don't see anywhere to choose something other than the percentages. I know that I can remove them, but I want to replace them.

[image: Example Chart]

I have tried tweaking the various label fields, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Please provide a link to a Google spreadsheet that exhibits the problem.  If you don't want to share from your own account, you can do it anonymously using [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)